# When can a List<T> have its Enumerator.Current always return null?

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I'm generating a List (I assume that  is immaterial - correct me if I'm wrong), and then iterating over it. The problem is that I'm calling GetEnumerator(), calling MoveNext on it, then accessing Current. No matter what I do, it's always returning null. There are plenty of items in the list, and I think it's properly formed.

I'm stymied... Any thoughts?

Yes, I know I haven't posted source code - I've tried a bunch of variants - it seems the only constant is that things break down when I call a helper class which accesses a database to populate my final list. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Why are you using `IEnumerable` directly? That's what `foreach` is for.

Comment: Also, please post your code or we'll have to close your Question.

Comment: `foreach` is very useful but it's not the only valid way to use an enumerator.

Comment: He's using IEnumerator to construct IEnumerable and that's what foreach does. there's nothing wrong in using IEnumerator

Answer (score 0):

That enumerator is a mutable struct. You probably box it by casting to the interface, which leads to `MoveNext` being called on a copy. Or you pass it to a method where you call `MoveNext`; again this will mutate a copy.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer - there were nulls in the List. Once the nulls were removed, all was well.